# Question about norm of linear operator's adjoint on a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Stein and Shakarchi state that for a bounded linear operator $P:H\to H$,  $||P||=||P^*||$, where $||P||=\sup\{|(Pf,g)|:||f||\le 1,\ ||g||\le 1,\ f,g\in H\}$.

Is it true that for any $f\in H$, $||Pf||=||P^*f||$? Sorry if this is obvious; I'm having trouble getting familiar with adjoints.

Comment: no, if $P$ be normal then you can say $||Pf||=||P^*f||$.

Comment: Great, thanks Razieh. If P is an orthogonal projection associated with a closed subspace S on H a Hilbert space, is P normal? This fact would help me prove P*=P.

Comment: An orthogonal projection associated with a closed subspace is selfadjoint which can be shown directly. To see this you need to show that $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$ for every $x, y$. To show this note that $id = P + (id -P)$ and the images of $P$ and $id - P $ are mutually orthogonal. So  $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle Px, Py +(id-P)y \rangle = \langle Px, Py \rangle = \langle Px + (id-P)x ,P y \rangle = \langle x,P y \rangle$

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I didn't follow your notation. What is id here? And if P is the operator, how can there be an image of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\|Pf\|\ne \|P^*f\|$. For example, 
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\  0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0  \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{ but }\quad
 \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\  0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0  \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}
$$
Generally, it's advisable to test one's ideas about Hilbert spaces on $\mathbb{R}^2$.